# Using fscanf to get 2 string in 2 columns

Tags: c, file-io, scanf

I'm trying to make my program read a file with 2 columns and the first column contains some strings and i cant make it to store into an array

Here is my code:

```
fp2=fopen("Symbol Table.txt","r");char str[100];
while(fscanf(fp2,"%s %s",str,stemp[scnt])!=NULL) {
    puts(stemp[scnt++]);getch();    //This is just here to display conents of second col
}
fclose(fp2)
```

and here is my txt file:

```
void                                                          void                                                          
main                                                          Main                                                          
(                                                             Left Parenthesis                                              
)                                                             Right Parenthesis                                             
{                                                             Left Brace                                                    
S                                                             Identifier                                                    
:                                                             Colon                                                        
$%                                                            Start of Block Comment                                        
This program is a simple calculatorFuctions:ADD,SUB,MULT,DIV  String                                                        
%$                                                            End of Block Comment                                          
Unsigned                                                      Noise Words                                                   
int                                                           Integer
```

the code store the long string is divided before going into the array

Comment: You need to use `while(fscanf(fp2,"%s %s",str,stemp[scnt])==2)`

Comment: its still the same the out of the puts in there is the same as before some parts of the long string is still stored in the second column array:(

Comment: try `while(fscanf(fp2,"%s %[^\n]", str, stemp[scnt])==2) {`

Answer (score 0):

When you try to read strings with `scanf` or `fscanf` it reads the string until it encounters a space, a tab, or a newline. In this case, as I can see, in the first loop the `str` and `stemp` will be assigned to the stings "void" and "void", in the second loop, it will be "main" and "Main" and in the third loop, "(" and "Left" and so on.

You need to separate the two columns with multiple strings with a special character like the tab (`\t`) character so that one knows when the 1st column ends and read with the `getc` function instead of `scanf` until you reach that special character in your line and then combine all the characters (i.e. letters) in to a string. You can adopt the same method to read the second column with a `getc` function until you encounter the newline (`\n`).

Answer (score 0):

The Nature of `while(fscanf(fp2,"%s %s",str,stemp[scnt])!=NULL)` is will read only the two string separated by a space. if your text file contains long strings like this

```
This program is a simple calculatorFuctions:ADD,SUB,MULT,DIV
```

While fetching it will divide this strings into parts of `%s %s` and fetch. So change your text file in the following way and try:

```
void                                                          void                                                          
main                                                          Main                 
(                                                             LeftParenthesis         
)                                                             RightParenthesis   
{                                                             LeftBrace   
S                                                             Identifier         
:                                                             Colon           
$%                                                            StartofBlockComment   
ThisProgramIsASimpleCalculatorFuctions:ADD,SUB,MULT,DIV       String 
%$                                                            EndofBlockComment 
Unsigned                                                      NoiseWords   
int                                                           Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

`while(fscanf(fp2,"%s %s",str,stemp[scnt])!=NULL) {`

is not going to work

`"%s"` scans for **non-** white-space text.  "This program is" and "Left Parenthesis" have embedded white-space.

Need to read a line-at-a-time and then parse the line into 2 strings for the 2 columns.

```
char buf[100];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp2) == NULL) Handle_EOForIOError();

column[2][100];
size_t len = strlen(buf);
if (len < 62) Handle_ShortLine();
buf[61] =  = '\0'; // cut the line in 2

column[0][0] = '\0';  // In case column is all white-space
sscanf(buf, " %[^\n]", column[0]);
column[1][0] = '\0';
sscanf(&buf[62], " %[^\n]", column[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers contain statements which are not true. Actually,

- `fscanf` does not always read strings only until a white-space character. The conversion specifier `[` also reads a string, and includes the set of expected characters.
- You do not need to separate the two columns with a special character, since the columns are of known width 62.
- You do not need to read a line at a time and then parse it; though, that might be easier.

So, if you prefer `fscanf`, you can use

```
    while (fscanf(fp2, "%62[^\n]%[^\n]\n", str, stemp[scnt]) == 2)
```

(your comparing with `NULL` is wrong, because `NULL` is a pointer constant and `fscanf` doesn't return a pointer but the number of input items assigned or EOF).

A version without `fscanf`:

```
    while (fgets(str, 62+1, fp2) && fgets(stemp[scnt], 62+1, fp2) && getc(fp2))
```

(The `getc` reads the `\n`.)